# SVG-image colour dependent on text colour, without external tools?

Tags: pdftex, color, sharelatex, text-decorations, svg

I have a decorative SVG-figure, and I want to change just one variable, to alter both text- and SVG-colour

Working in Sharelatex, using pdfLatex to compile

SVG to retain its scaling properties

## MWE

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{that-theme-of-mine}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \includesvg{rectangle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

that-theme-of-mine.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage{that-theme-of-mine}

% Enables setting text colour
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Defining my specially chosen colour as #dcdccc
\definecolor{my-special-colour}{HTML}{dcdccc}

% Setting the text colour to be my special colour
\color{my-special-colour}
```

rectangle.svg

```
<svg>
<rect width="100" height="100" fill="#ff5566"/>
</svg>
```

## Tried

- `\VerbatimInput{\mycolour}{ffff00}` into the theme-file before "My colour scheme": `<svg><rect width="100" height="100" fill="#\mycolour"/></svg>` and `\definecolor{page-colour}{HTML}{\mycolour}` under "Background and text colour"
- `\newcommand\x{30}` - From [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175424/8467) to [Define numeric variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175413/define-numeric-variables) - No effect. Seems to only support 0-9 anyway
- `\begin{figure}\color{red}` from [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161089/8467) to [Change text color when inserting a pdf_tex image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161074/change-text-color-when-inserting-a-pdf-tex-image) - Couldn't even force a colour onto a rectangle without fill

## Next

- Inkscape through Sharelatex somehow? I get error messages mentioning Inkscape sometimes, but documentation on the two combined seems flimsy
- Exploring [decodearray](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150219/8467)?
- TikZ?

## Related questions:

### - [Can \includegraphics be used to change an image color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29227/can-includegraphics-be-used-to-change-an-image-color)

Comment: The SVG package convert the SVG image to PDF (using Inkscape, I think) before to give it to LaTeX. So controlling the color in SVG is (almost) the same as controlling the color in external PDF. Probably it will be simpler to convert your SVG image to TikZ and then control the color.

Comment: @Kpym Looks like it. Fiddled with svg2tikz, and the simplest way right now was to install Inkscape (Portable) on Windows, add the 3 files from svg2tikz to InkscapePortable/App/Inkscape/share/extensions - then open the SVG with Inkscape - Extensions - Export - Export to TikZ path… - select "Tikzpicture" and "Export to clipboard". \definecolor works with TikZ.